# How to change a specific tag in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i really can't get my head around something. The thing is that i'm working on a canvas with multiple shapes on it, like circles or rectangles. I want to modify a specific tag and  i couldn't find anything useful on this subject.

```
 self.entry=workspace.create_rectangle(10,10,40,40, fill = "red",tag = "false"
```

this is how i create my rectangle inside a class and what i want to do is modify that specific tag from "false" to "true"

Comment: Objects can have an arbitrary number of tags. You don't change "the" tag; you add and delete tags. In your case, you want to remove `"false"` and add `"true"`.

Answer (score 0):

[`itemconfig`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) is conventionally used to change the property of a canvas item after creation. Example:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> workspace = tkinter.Canvas()
>>> x = workspace.create_rectangle(10,10,40,40, fill="red", tag="false")
>>> workspace.itemconfig(x, tag="true")
>>> print(workspace.itemcget(x, "tag"))
true
```

Comment: My experience tonight is totally different for `.itemconfig` and `.itemcget`.